# C# - Displaying progress indicator or spinner in PowerShell module

Tags: c#, powershell

In C#, is there an easy way to display a spinner, or alternatively, a progress indicator of indeterminate length in a custom Powershell Cmdlet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some help [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/WriteProgressCmdlet.cs) for progress bars